# Response headers are different from browser when performed with requests.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

When performing the below HTTP request using the Python requests library, the response is as shown below:

```
headers = {
'Host': 'cgaxis.com',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': '489',
'Origin': 'https://cgaxis.com',
'TE':'Trailers',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://cgaxis.com/product/christmas-table-decoration-3/',
'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1349896001.1573562165; _gid=GA1.2.1103188066.1573562165; _fbp=fb.1.1573562177263.1142673466; wordpress_logged_in_d654bb6ee10d524ec9b993121bc1de21=b9s%7C1573735076%7CaAPERAC1MmoIXqoQf305isXZa2HkK5owmBgZLK2yupj%7C718ee60eaf0dbaf85ffa2f6402becac567766fbdb08be1f3ac8c99b446907ecf; __stripe_mid=14074cc0-abe8-497d-93e3-329937272fbd; wfwaf-authcookie-4f48e79d1a332c22b28650e533988cc5=13050%7Csubscriber%7C9e787a4d89f8e0ae9354672ae69bd3e3162c38d316095512c8983cd6d17aebc5; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; __stripe_sid=ffed8ccc-0e78-4967-9ad8-6fa8fcef9fad; cookie_notice_accepted=true; _gat=1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1'
}

data = {'body':'somdn_download_key=MTU3MzYyMzE5Ng%3D%3D&billing_first_name=Benjamin&billing_last_name=Gallais&billing_company=Dassault+Syst%C3%A8mes+SE&billing_country=FR&billing_address_1=10%2C+Rue+Marcel+Dassault+CS+40501&billing_address_2=&billing_postcode=78946&billing_city=VELIZY+VILLACOUBLAY+CEDEX&billing_state=&billing_phone=%2B33+1+55+35+26+27&billing_email=b9s%403ds.com&vat_number=FR52322306440&customer_location_self_certified=&payment_method=&action=somdn_download_single&somdn_product=16950'}

response = requests.post('https://cgaxis.com/product/christmas-table-decoration-3/', data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

response.status_code,response.headers
```

And the response I get is:

`status code = 200`

response headers:

```
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
date →Wed, 13 Nov 2019 06:46:08 GMT
link →<https://cgaxis.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://cgaxis.com/?p=16950>; rel=shortlink
server →nginx
status →200
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options →nosniff
```

But in the browser (network tab in developer tools), the request and the response header for the same is:

**REQUEST HEADER:**

```
POST /product/christmas-table-decoration-1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: cgaxis.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://cgaxis.com/product/christmas-table-decoration-1/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 489
Origin: https://cgaxis.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __stripe_mid=522a5f57-0570-42de-9a74-44c3b4d82f13; wordpress_logged_in_d654bb6ee10d524ec9b993121bc1de21=b9s%7C1573728390%7CpjCzZcjGFKhyJUvMdYxADvPencBDvQNqv4H1Pqhfhky%7Cedd40cfc2f3f323738c74e28d0209c3ed05f7874f1129bb5700b1ff127f43e84
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

**REQUEST PAYLOAD:**

```
somdn_download_key=MTU3MzU2MDEzNQ%3D%3D&billing_first_name=Benjamin&billing_last_name=Gallais&billing_company=Dassault+Syst%C3%A8mes+SE&billing_country=FR&billing_address_1=10%2C+Rue+Marcel+Dassault+CS+40501&billing_address_2=&billing_postcode=78946&billing_city=VELIZY+VILLACOUBLAY+CEDEX&billing_state=&billing_phone=%2B33+1+55+35+26+27&billing_email=b9s%403ds.com&vat_number=FR52322306440&customer_location_self_certified=&payment_method=&action=somdn_download_single&somdn_product=16686
```

**RESPONSE HEADER:**

```
HTTP/2.0 302 Found
server: nginx
date: Wed, 13 Nov 2019 06:16:58 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
access-control-allow-origin: https://cgaxis.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
vary: Origin
location: https://cgaxis.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/amz/Volume-039/single_models/cgaxis_models_volume_39_20.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=JJXE3XDR6KI4A3AMOVSE%2F20191113%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191113T061658Z&X-Amz-Expires=1200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1aa97d6443cd1861b2b9e03e32dcebaf4fd59e3293b99153b41534a030207975
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I need the `location` parameter in the above response in order use with `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Are you asking how to not follow the redirect? And if you want to not follow the redirect so that you can use the Location URL to follow the redirect, why? Also why are you using both requests and urllib?

Comment: `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` is to automate the downloading of files without a browser.
I'm using the requests library to post the request with the specific body and headers.
I'm a beginner in python...if there is a better way to go about this...please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same response make sure you also send the same request.

Probably the response from the browser is a result of an OPTION request and not POST. You can see this in network tab inside the browser. Posting the original request of the second response allows us to help you more

Also know that, web server can have different responses per user-agent. Try to set the user agent header in your pythov code so it looks like coming from a browser.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the request and response header and the request payload from the browser.
The user-agent is also set same as in the Browsers request header.
And in the Network tab, it is mentioned as a POST request with a status code of 302

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting redirected when you are calling it from the browser. 
So to mimic the same behaviour while making a call from the python library, you should use  allow_redirects=False parameter.

```
response = requests.post('https://cgaxis.com/product/christmas-table-decoration-3/', data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

This will ensure that you don't get automatically redirected to the location attribute. After this, you can extract the location attribute from the response headers and make the subsequent call.

Comment: setting `allow_redirects=False` gives the same response.
Both the status code and the response headers are same